# Unable to remove ZFS cache device created on another operating system

Tags: linux, zfs, proxmox

I used to run SmartOS (Solaris) on a server, but recently moved to Proxmox (Linux). A non-root zpool that was exported from SmartOS was successfully imported to Proxmox - except for the cache device (which was offline at the time). `zpool status archive` now shows:

```
  pool: archive
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices could not be used because the label is missing or
    invalid.  Sufficient replicas exist for the pool to continue
    functioning in a degraded state.
action: Replace the device using 'zpool replace'.
   see: https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/msg/ZFS-8000-4J
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 13:25:18 with 0 errors on Tue Feb  1 15:26:18 2022
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    archive     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs
      sdb       ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      c4d0s0    UNAVAIL      0     0     0
```

As this is a Linux system and I have seen reports of random problems using a cache device, I have decided not to reinstate it. Unfortunately

```
zpool remove archive c4d0s0
```

fails with

```
cannot remove c4d0s0: no such device in pool
```

Which is not really surprising as the device name is not a format recognised by Linux.

I tried using `zdb` to find the GID of the missing cache device, but nothing shows up. Any ideas on how to delete this device?

Comment: Have you try to replace the caching device?

Comment: And I do not see any relation between SmartOS and Solaris. Please clarify

Comment: Romeo, SmartOS is based on OpenSolaris. 
The cache device doesn’t exist anymore. It was re-assigned.

Comment: Are you able to use a rescue environment, preferably a Solaris-based one? Does make a read-only imported pool able to remove the missing vdev?

Comment: That's an interesting angle, @Amitie10g
I'll try that next time I take the system down.